# Notation involving "Smooth Functions of Compact Support."

Tags: real-analysis, notation

I'm reading a paper that regularly refers to the space: $\mathcal{C}_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ as "Smooth functions of compact support."

For added context, it's used in such a way as to illustrate a special case (note this is heavily simplified -- it's not a direct quote):

"We define the operator $F^*$ of $g \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$  as:
$$ F^* g(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}}g(\theta, x \cdot \theta) d\theta$$
This is the integral of $g$ over all lines through x, and perpendicular to $\theta$. Let $g$ be a smooth function of compact support, $g \in \mathcal{C}_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then...."

I can not find a decent source for this notation. Previous works / works-cited do not venture into these-types of special cases (whereas this paper spends most of it's time in this $\mathcal{C}_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ space.)

If this is some sort of standard notation, does it guarantee a smoothness order? 1? $\infty$?

Comment: Sometimes, *smooth* is used to mean *sufficiently regular*, that is all the quantities are well-defined and all the properties needed to do the computations are satisfied. In most cases, *smooth* means $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$. Maybe you can provide us a link to the paper in order to get more accurate answers.

Comment: Thank you!

Yes, here's the paper I'm reading: 

[http://equinto.math.tufts.edu/research/sc-article.pdf](http://equinto.math.tufts.edu/research/sc-article.pdf)

Comment: Further complicating matters, he actually refers to both $\mathcal{C}_c$ and $\mathcal{C}_c^\infty$. (See eq (2.5)+)

Comment: From what I have seen, the author used smooth compactly supported functions when dealing with the Fourier transform. The Fourier transform behaves nicely on the Schwartz space, that is the Fourier transform is an isomorphism on the Schwartz space. Since the compactly supported functions which are in $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ are dense in the Schwartz space, I would assume $\mathcal{C}_c$ means $\mathcal{C}_c^{\infty}$.

Comment: Strangely, he uses **both** notations, though. In addition, why not use $\mathcal{C}_0^\infty$? (I see this notation used regularly... the sub-c has thrown me off all day!)

Comment: Indeed, I have just noticed your comment, that is somewhat strange. Howeover, I have seen both notations $\mathcal{C}_0^{\infty}$ and $\mathcal{C}_c^{\infty}$ for $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$-functions which are compactly supported. My distribution theory lecturer prefers $\mathcal{C}_0^{\infty}$ and my harmonic analysis one is fond of $\mathcal{C}_c^{\infty}$.

Comment: Well, in Mama Rudin $C_c(X)$ stands for the class of complex valued continuous functions on the topological space $X$ with compact support, so it certainly is not "standard" notation in the strict sense. But then again, maybe in general practice $C_c$ is the class of functions with compact support in the relevant category.